Proof of existence of algebraic closure with Zorn's lemma
I read the proof of existence of algebraic closure by Zorn's lemma, whose idea is to to consider the "set"
$$
\mathcal{P} := \{ K \mid \text{the algebraic extension of } F \}.
$$
Using Zorn's lemma, one can show that $(\mathcal{P}, \subset)$ has a maximal element, which is an algebraic closure of $F$. The only problem is that $\mathcal{P}$ is actually not a set but  a class, hence we cannot apply  Zorn's lemma on it.
However, I wonder if the following consideration works. Let us fix a Grothendieck universe $\mathcal{U}$, which is big enough for most cases. In the future, we only consider $\mathcal{U}$-sets, $\mathcal{U}$-groups, $\mathcal{U}$-fields and so on. Now
$$
\mathcal{P} := \{ K \mid \text{the $\mathcal{U}$-algebraic extension of } F \}
$$
is indeed a set, hence we can apply Zorn's lemma on it.
The only thing I worry about is whether something wrong will appear when we play Zorn's lemma over sets "as big as the fixed Grothendieck universe", such as $\mathcal{P}$.

If you want to worry about axioms you should state what system you are working in. Typically one assumes the axiom of choice for all sets. That includes the Grothendieck universe $U$, which is a set, and much bigger things besides.

This is a perfectly valid approach. But notice that the existence of a Grothendieck universe is independent from ZFC. This is why this approach is probably usually not taken. On the other hand, the existence of Grothendieck universes is useful and also used in so many contexts nowadays, that it is also not a big deal. And I will explain why your proof eventually does not need Grothendieck universes anyway.
Let me recall how Zorn's Lemma follows from the axiom of choice. Then we use this to construct the algebraic closure with your idea.
Let $(P,\leq)$ be a partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound, which however has no maximal element. By the axiom of choice, we have a function that chooses an upper bound for every chain, and for every element another element strictly above it. We then define a strictly increasing function $f : \mathbf{On} \to P$ by transfinite recursion as follows. If $\alpha$ is an ordinal number and all $f(\beta)$ for $\beta < \alpha$ have been defined, then let $p \in P$ be the chosen upper bound of the chain $\{f(\beta) : \beta < \alpha\}$, and finally let $f(\alpha) \in P$ be the chosen element $p < f(\alpha)$. Then $f(\beta) < f(\alpha)$ for all $\beta < \alpha$. So $f$ is an injective function from the class of ordinals to a set, which cannot exist, say by Hartog's Lemma. $\checkmark$
Informally, the construction constructs the maximal element of $P$ as follows. Start with any element of $P$. If it is maximal, done. If not, take an element which is larger. Take an element which is larger, etc. If you have infinitely many elements, which are strictly increasing already, take an upper bound. If that is maximal, done. Otherwise, increase that one even more. Then you have an element which is strictly larger than all the previous elements. Continue this ordinal many times. At some stage this process has to stop, though. We will find a maximal element.
In our case, $P$ is the set of algebraic extensions of $K$ in the universe $\mathcal{U}$. Notice that $P \notin \mathcal{U}$, but we still may work in the collection of all sets (or sets in $\mathcal{U}^+$ for an even larger universe $\mathcal{U}^+$, if you like). For algebraic extensions $L,L'$ of $K$ we write $L \leq L'$ when $L$ is a subfield of $L'$ in the usual sense. The empty chain has an upper bound, the extension $K$ of $K$. If $C \subseteq P$ is a non-empty chain, then one checks that $\bigcup C$ is an upper bound of $C$ in $P$.
Therefore, by Zorn's Lemma, there is a maximal element of $(P,\leq)$. It is an algebraic extension $L$ of $K$ in $\mathcal{U}$ such that for every other algebraic extension $L'$ in $\mathcal{U}$ with $L \subseteq L'$ we have $L = L'$. But then, $L$ must be an algebraic closure of $K$. This means that $L = \overline{K}$ is algebraic over $K$ and that every monic polynomial over $K$ splits into linear factors over $L$. This more elementary property makes it clear that $\overline{K}$ is also maximal with respect to all algebraic extensions of $K$, regardless whether they lie in $\mathcal{U}$ or not.
By the preceding discussion, we may construct $\overline{K}$ as follows. If $K$ is algebraically closed, done. If not, take a proper algebraic extension of $K$. Take a proper algebraic extension of that. Continue. If you have infinitely many strictly increasing algebraic extensions of $K$, take their union, and a strict algebraic extension of that (if it doesn't exist, we would be done). Continue ordinal many times. At some point we have found a maximal element, an algebraic closure.
The point is, however, that we don't need to repeat this process so many times. Here is a more refined construction of $\overline{K}$.
For every monic $f \in K[T]$, recall that $K[T]/\langle f \rangle$ is a $K$-algebra in which $f$ has a root. It follows immediately that the tensor product of $K$-algebras $\bigotimes_{f \in K[T] \text{ monic}} K[T] / \langle f \rangle$ has the property that every $f$ has a root inside it. By linear algebra, it is non-zero (in fact, an explicit $K$-basis is known). Hence, it has a maximal ideal (axiom of choice). Then, the quotient by that maximal ideal is an algebraic field extension $K'$ of $K$ such that every monic polynomial over $K$ has a root in $K'$. Now the union of $K \subseteq K' \subseteq K'' \subseteq \cdots$ is an algebraic closure of $K$. (Actually, but that it is non-trivial, we have $\overline{K} = K'$ already.)
This means that we just need to run our transfinite construction once for every polynomial, and then repeat that countably many times. We don't need all ordinal numbers. We know exactly when the process ends. And in particular, we see that the choice of the Grothendieck universe does not make any difference, and that we don't need it (just the axiom of choice).

I think it's quite generous to call this a "perfectly valid approach" given that it does not produce a proof from ZFC.

You would be amazed how many papers and books dealing with foundations of category theory, algebraic geometry, homotopy theory, homological algebra etc. use Grothendieck universes. ZFC is just one snapshot in the history of popular set theories. I prefer TG. There is nothing universal about ZFC, from a pure mathematical perspective. Also, notice that the OP explicitly asked a question given a Grothendieck universe, so it's not really a concern anyway. And finally, I showed how to get rid of the universe afterwards.

@Adayah: From a formalist perspective, you can think of the first approach in Martin's answer as a proof in ZFC of "there exists a Grothendieck universe $\to$ every field has an algebraic closure". On the other hand, I think the vast majority of set theorists with a Platonist bent believe that Grothendieck universes appear in the cumulative hierarchy. Note also that ZFC cannot prove Con(ZFC), but that doesn't stop it from being a true arithmetic statement.

I don't think that the way that book authors handle highly advanced and abstract topics like category theory etc. is relevant here. The existence of algebraic closures of fields is an elementary fact and ZFC is well established as the set-theoretical foundation of mathematics as a whole. To me the usage of the Grothendieck universe here looks outstandingly unnecessary and superfluous. Not to mention, it gives a weaker variant of the proof (because it assumes more set theory).

Also, notice that the facts that the question was specifically about the GU or that you showed how to not use the GU afterwards - have no bearing on whether using GU in the first place is perfectly valid.

I don't know about the Grothendieck universe, but a standard way to resolve such set-theoretical issues is as follows.* We fix a set $X$ with $|X| > |K| + \aleph_0$ and an injective map $i : K \to X$. Now we take $\mathcal{P}$ as the family of all fields $(L, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$ such that

$i[K] \subseteq L \subseteq X$,
$i : K \to L$ is a field embedding,
the extension $i[K] \subseteq L$ is algebraic.

Such $\mathcal{P}$ is clearly a set. Then we order $\mathcal{P}$ by the relation of being a subfield.
In this setting we can use the Zorn's lemma and the usual proof goes through. There is maybe one bit that needs adjusting: when proving by contradiction that the maximal element $L$ of $\mathcal{P}$ is algebraically closed, we need to carefully move the structure from $L[X]/(w)$ to a set $M$ such that $L \subseteq M \subseteq X$ so that the constructed field is still in $\mathcal{P}$.
*Well ok, a standard way is to ignore these issues completely until pressed sufficiently hard. :P

Of course, it is important to choose $X$ big enough in this approach. In this case we can, because the number of polynomials over $K$ is bounded by some cardinal, and the number of possible roots per polynomial is bounded.

Also, I think you meant to say that $L \subseteq X$ in the first paragraph?

@MarkKamsma Right, it was initially there but got lost in the editing phase. Thanks.

This does not answer the question being asked. It was about if the approach with Grothendieck universes works. The construction in your post is standard and already has appeared on MSE before, no need to repeat it really.

@MartinBrandenburg Indeed. The question being answered here is asked in the linked post, and several alternatives were presented. Speaking of the linked post, there is a deleted answer that uses Grothendieck universes. Asaf Karagila commented, "The answer equivalent to 'if you want to kill a mosquito turn the sun into a black hole'..."

@MartinBrandenburg I am aware that I did not directly answer the question. But I did want to challenge the frame a little bit: I think the Grothendieck universe is a superfluous tool here. During my studies I never even learned about it, while the construction from my answer should be completely within any algebra student's toolbox. If the OP actually really only wanted to know about the GU method, I admit I missed the question.

As for re-writing constructions that appeared on MSE before, it is easier for me to do it from scratch than to find them (especially ones that are sufficiently well written). Also, the flavour of these answers would never be completely equivalent to the one that I can write myself.

In case, $K$ is finite, you need that $X$ is infinite (countable infinite suffices), since algebraically closed fields are infinite.

@Ulli You're right, I meant $|X| > |K| + \aleph_0$. In particular, I think we need $|X| \geqslant \aleph_1$ in case when $K$ is finite? Of course $|X| = \aleph_0$ is enough to contain the algebraic closure. But it is not enough to ensure that anything smaller than the algebraic closure can be extended within $X$.
